# Accept only Double Values in a JTextField using DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing, double, jtextfield, documentfilter

Is there any way to accept only double values in a JTextField using documentfilter?

Comment: I'm a little confused at what you mean. Do you mean they could enter any number? Thats just a sequence of digits with one optional dot and an optional plus or minus on the front. Or is there more you want?

Comment: Does an `int` or a `float` count as a `double`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

This will allow you to "filter" the incoming content before it reaches the document.

Check out [these examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more ideas

You could also try look at a [`JFormattedTxtField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) which would probably be easier, but where's the fun in that

Comment: please post few examples for document filter.

Comment: Check out the examples links, hey are better then nothing I could post